# Consistency of a System of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Test the consistency of the system of linear equations

$$\begin{align} 4x-5y+z & =2 \\ 3x+y-2z& = 9 \\ x+4y+z& =5\end{align}$$

Comment: Show us some work and what your confusion/difficulty is in solving it.

Comment: @RwitamJana: Welcome to MSE! Does the system have no solution, a single solution or infinite solutions? What methods have you learned to solve it? What is the definition of consistency? In other words, what have you tried to solve this? Regards

Answer (score 5):

We have the system of linear equations given by: $$\begin{align} 4x-5y+z & =2\\ \\ 3x+y-2z& = 9 \\ \\ x+4y+z& =5\end{align}$$

This system can be represented by either of the following augmented coefficient matrices:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 4 & -5 & 1 &\mid 2 \\ 3 & 1 & -2 &\mid  9 \\ 1 & 4 & 1 &\mid 5\end{pmatrix}\to \quad \text{Swap Row 1 with Row 3}\to \quad \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 1 & \mid 5 \\ 3 & 1 & -2 & \mid 9 \\ 4 & -5 & 1 & \mid 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

On the second matrix, we can continue to perform elementary row operations to row reduce the matrix (i.e. using Gaussian Elimination) in order to check for consistency. Does this sound familiar?

If we row reduce to obtain a row, e.g., of $(0 \; 0 \; 0 \; c)$ where $c$ is non-zero, we have an *inconsistent* system. Else, the system is consistent. Consistency simplyy means: Can all equations simultaneously be true? If so, then the system is consistent. If not, then it is inconsistent. When a system is inconsistent, no solution can possibly exist. When it is consistent, either a unique solution exists, or infinitely many solutions exist.

If you row reduce correctly, to reduced row echelon form, you should obtain the matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 &\mid 2\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \mid 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \mid -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now, what can you say about the system's consistency?

Comment: please solve it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have to solve it with Gauss elimination method?

Comment: Rwitam Jana - Please feel free to follow up with your conclusion to my last question. I'll be happy to confirm, or correct, your thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

4. Examine the consistency for following system and solve if consistent.
   $$3x + y +2z = 3,$$      $$2x – 3y – z = -3,$$      $$x + 2y + z = 4$$