# Consider the surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^ 3$ given by the graph of $f(x, y) = xy^2 − 2y^2 + e^x $.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Consider the surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by the graph of $f(x, y) = xy^2 − 2y^2 + e^x$
.
Calculate the intersection point of the tangent planes to $S$ above $(x, y) = (0, 0), (0, 1)$, and $(0, 2)$.

Can someone guide me through solving this problem? I am confused on where to start because we didn't cover this in class. Thanks so much

Comment: Are you sure you were not asked to find the **equations** of the tangent planes?

Comment: Yes, this is the exact wording of the problem

Comment: I asked because the intersection of the tangent plane at the point of the surface above the point $(x_0,y_0)$ is just the point of the surface $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ where $z_0=f(x_0,y_0)$. This gives the points $(0,0,1),\,(0,1,-1)$ and $(0,2,-7)$.

Comment: OK, I get it now. I misinterpreted the question. You are looking for the intersection point of the three tangent planes, not the three points where the tangent planes intersect the surface. You will have to find the linear equations for each of the three and solve a system of three linear equations.

Comment: That’s right, any idea how I can go about solving this?

Comment: @gimusi has shown you how to find the linear equation of each plane. That will give you three linear equations to solve. Evidently the system is supposed to be independent so you should be able to find a single solution.

Comment: You already asked this here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547901/consider-the-surface-s-in-bbb-r3-given-by-the-graph-of-fx-y-find-the/2547959#2547959

Comment: I answered your question without writing everything out, was that the problem?

Comment: Jennifer, why you make us work twice?

Comment: I just noticed Faraad's answer. Sorry, my fault!

Comment: @JenniferHall you can set as solved if you are ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation for the tangent plane at the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is:

$$z-z_0=f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$$

As an example for point $P_1(0,0)$:

$$f_x = y^2+e^x \implies f_x(0,0)=1$$
$$f_y = 2xy-4y \implies f_y(0,0)=0$$
$$z_0 = f(0,0)=1$$

Thus the equation of the plane through $P_1(0,0)$ is:

$$z-1=1\cdot(x-0)+0 \cdot(y-0) \implies x-z=-1$$

Similary the equation of the plane through $P_2(0,1)$ is:

$$z+1=2\cdot(x-0)-4 \cdot(y-1) \implies 2x-4y-z=-3$$

Finally the equation of the plane through $P_3(0,2)$ is:

$$z+7=5\cdot(x-0)-8 \cdot(y-2) \implies 5x-8y-z=-9$$

Once you have found the equations for the three planes you need to solve the system of linear equations to find the intersection point.

For the solution of the system of equations as an example take a look here:
[Consistency of a System of linear equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502534/consistency-of-a-system-of-linear-equations)

The final solution should be: **P(-2,0,-1)**.

**NOTE** check calculation detail by yourself trying to understand each step

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I solved the equations for the three planes and got the same answers you did. How would I solve it to find the intersection point now?

Comment: a good tool is wolfy http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x-z%3D-1,2x-4y-z%3D-3,5x-8y-z%3D-9, but try to solve by hand if you want understand deeply what it's going on